# Failed JUnit4 test cases in Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test, java-11, java-module

I am writing Spring Boot **modular** application with Java 11 (Amazon Coretto Open JDK).

Test cases are running fine using IDE but it fails when ran from Command Line.

Upon running the command

```
mvn clean test
```

I get long error message log mostly focusing on

```
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException-->module com.application.user does not open com.application.user to unnamed module @33723e30
```

Test cases run fine from Command Line once I **export** and **open** the packages suggested but it breaks the core concept of Modularity in my application if I export all the packages.

Is it possible to run the test cases without exporting and opening the packages?